# I want to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and SQL Server 2008 Express on the same machine, which should I install first?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I want to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise and SQL Server 2008 Express side-by-side on the same machine, which should I install first for a simpler install process and easier maintenance in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005, I ALWAYS had to install the full product first, then Express second. If I did it the other way around, the full SQL install would see Express installed already, and would not continue with the install. It was extremely annoying. Not sure if they fixed this with 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I would install the Enterprise version first, with all the tools (Management Studio), then the small version of the Express (not Advanced Services), so it doesn't try anything funny.